# Problem of initial value and inequality

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Be the differential equation

$$ \tag{$*$} \begin{cases} y' = \displaystyle \frac{\cos(y)}{1 + y^4} \\[6pt]
                 y(0)= \displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2} \end{cases} $$ 
and, we know that exists a constant $L \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for any $s,r \in \mathbb{R}$
$$ \left|\frac{\cos(s)}{1 + s^4}-\frac{\cos(r)}{1 + r^4} \ \right| \leq L|s-r|$$.

Show that the solution of $(*)$ is unique and is the function $\phi(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: $y(x)=const$ is definitely not a solution to  (*) because $y'(0) =\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \frac{1}{1+(\pi/4)^4}>0$. But what is $\phi$?

Comment: I was referring to the initial form of the problem 1 hour ago which had $y(0) =  \pi /4$ (cf. also the answer of rebellos). Now with $y(0) =  \pi /2$ all drivatives are zero at $x=0$ from which the result follows without any complicated additional condition.

Comment: Since the variables are separated you can find the general solution of the ODE  in the form $x=x(y)$ in terms of $\log$ and $\text{Li}$ (polylog).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition you are given :

$$\left|\frac{\cos(s)}{1 + s^4}-\frac{\cos(r)}{1 + r^4} \ \right| \leq L|s-r|$$

means that your RHS function is considered a ***Lipschitz*** one.

That's because when you have an IVP like the one you have :

$$\begin{cases} y' = \displaystyle \frac{\cos(y)}{1 + y^4} \\
                 y(0)= \displaystyle \frac{\pi}{4} \end{cases}$$

you have to study the behavior of the RHS of the function at the differential equation, specifically :

$$y'=\frac{\cos(y)}{1+y^4}=f(y)$$

Now, one can easily see that the condition you're given, is :

$$\left|\frac{\cos(s)}{1 + s^4}-\frac{\cos(r)}{1 + r^4} \ \right| \leq L|s-r| \Rightarrow|f(s) - f(r)| \leq L|s-r|$$

Since $L$ is a constan $\in \mathbb R$, it's obviously independent of $s,r$ which means that this relation states that the function :

$$f(y) = \frac{\cos(y)}{1+y^4}$$

is a ***Lipschitz*** function, which can be interpret as that the derivative of the RHS $f'(y)$ is bounded (you can easily check this by differentiation or by the ***Mean Value Theorem***). But on the same time, this is the case for an IVP to have a unique solution, thus it's true that your given IVP has a unique solution around $x=0$ and generally.

I think your given function that represents a solution is wrong though, as stated in the comments.